# Google Chart PHP JSON error

Tags: json, csv, charts, google-visualization

I wrote this code to display data:

```
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://precursori.altervista.org/php_test/tojson.php', false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    var jsonData = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Data/Ora');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Portata');
    console.log(jsonData);
    //data.addRows(jsonData);
    data.addRows([["2017-04-20T14:50:06+02:00",48.844063],["2017-04-20T14:56:13+02:00",45.562233],["2017-04-20T14:56:38+02:00",59.353275],["2017-04-20T14:57:39+02:00",49.73119],["2017-04-20T14:58:39+02:00",56.524372],["2017-04-20T14:59:39+02:00",41.522316],["2017-04-20T15:00:39+02:00",51.057808],["2017-04-20T15:01:40+02:00",47.801426],["2017-04-20T15:02:40+02:00",50.577076],["2017-04-20T15:03:40+02:00",50.79332],["2017-04-20T15:04:40+02:00",46.376625],["2017-04-20T15:05:40+02:00",46.79598],["2017-04-20T15:06:41+02:00",52.501205],["2017-04-20T15:07:44+02:00",42.061905],["2017-04-20T15:08:44+02:00",56.107132],["2017-04-20T15:09:44+02:00",45.90068],["2017-04-20T15:10:45+02:00",47.9056],["2017-04-20T15:11:45+02:00",58.107994],["2017-04-20T15:12:45+02:00",45.538834],["2017-04-20T15:13:46+02:00",41.64712],["2017-04-20T15:14:46+02:00",41.536926],["2017-04-20T15:15:46+02:00",40.799664],["2017-04-20T15:16:49+02:00",41.73109],["2017-04-20T15:17:49+02:00",56.898544],["2017-04-20T15:18:50+02:00",50.87478],["2017-04-20T15:19:50+02:00",43.92292],["2017-04-20T15:20:50+02:00",56.263924],["2017-04-20T15:21:51+02:00",42.295776],["2017-04-20T15:22:52+02:00",59.79318],["2017-04-20T15:23:52+02:00",48.92842],["2017-04-20T15:24:53+02:00",44.39889],["2017-04-20T15:25:53+02:00",43.253876],["2017-04-20T15:26:53+02:00",59.467987],["2017-04-20T15:27:53+02:00",40.13568],["2017-04-20T15:28:53+02:00",43.848824],["2017-04-20T15:29:53+02:00",43.02753],["2017-04-20T15:30:53+02:00",51.230713],["2017-04-20T15:31:53+02:00",40.074753],["2017-04-20T15:32:53+02:00",40.175735],["2017-04-20T15:33:53+02:00",44.07906],["2017-04-20T15:34:54+02:00",47.89345],["2017-04-20T15:35:54+02:00",48.18459],["2017-04-20T15:36:55+02:00",47.09455],["2017-04-20T15:37:57+02:00",56.787807],["2017-04-20T15:38:57+02:00",43.48187],["2017-04-20T15:39:57+02:00",41.108017],["2017-04-20T15:40:57+02:00",53.5978],["2017-04-20T15:41:57+02:00",55.04689],["2017-04-20T15:42:58+02:00",55.16123],["2017-04-20T15:43:58+02:00",54.72036],["2017-04-20T15:44:58+02:00",54.836876],["2017-04-20T15:45:58+02:00",53.9288],["2017-04-20T15:46:58+02:00",40.834328],["2017-04-20T15:47:58+02:00",56.50905],["2017-04-20T15:48:58+02:00",48.165512],["2017-04-20T15:49:58+02:00",44.60322],["2017-04-20T15:50:58+02:00",48.402992],["2017-04-20T15:51:58+02:00",42.004654],["2017-04-20T15:52:59+02:00",41.79945],["2017-04-20T15:53:59+02:00",48.10961],["2017-04-20T15:54:59+02:00",51.550922],["2017-04-20T15:55:59+02:00",55.981598],["2017-04-20T15:57:01+02:00",42.36441],["2017-04-20T15:58:02+02:00",52.286686],["2017-04-20T15:59:02+02:00",57.22363],["2017-04-20T16:00:02+02:00",53.744156],["2017-04-20T16:01:03+02:00",44.446266],["2017-04-20T16:02:03+02:00",57.816994],["2017-04-20T16:03:03+02:00",53.41036],["2017-04-20T16:04:03+02:00",50.94689],["2017-04-20T16:05:03+02:00",44.43931],["2017-04-20T16:06:03+02:00",40.445213],["2017-04-20T16:07:04+02:00",45.596634],["2017-04-20T16:08:04+02:00",43.338264],["2017-04-20T16:09:04+02:00",50.88922],["2017-04-20T16:10:04+02:00",40.27484],["2017-04-20T16:11:04+02:00",56.138893],["2017-04-20T16:12:04+02:00",47.14354],["2017-04-20T16:13:04+02:00",41.588875],["2017-04-20T16:14:04+02:00",46.752262],["2017-04-20T16:15:04+02:00",54.162697],["2017-04-20T16:16:05+02:00",53.41317],["2017-04-20T16:17:05+02:00",55.410496],["2017-04-20T16:18:05+02:00",43.43647],["2017-04-20T16:19:05+02:00",42.31321],["2017-04-20T16:20:05+02:00",47.762146],["2017-04-20T16:21:07+02:00",54.814144],["2017-04-20T16:22:08+02:00",51.664036],["2017-04-20T16:23:08+02:00",50.263695],["2017-04-20T16:24:10+02:00",53.034424],["2017-04-20T16:25:10+02:00",47.788372],["2017-04-20T16:26:11+02:00",51.304386],["2017-04-20T16:27:11+02:00",59.349754],["2017-04-20T16:28:11+02:00",54.375923],["2017-04-20T16:29:11+02:00",59.345886],["2017-04-20T16:30:11+02:00",52.322174],["2017-04-20T16:31:11+02:00",45.641865],["2017-04-20T16:32:11+02:00",52.13485],["2017-04-20T16:33:11+02:00",50.36891],["2017-04-20T16:34:11+02:00",47.998077],["2017-04-20T16:35:11+02:00",54.35617],["2017-04-20T16:36:12+02:00",51.385788],["2017-04-20T16:37:12+02:00",52.392178],["2017-04-20T16:38:12+02:00",42.394722],["2017-04-20T16:39:12+02:00",42.45667],["2017-04-20T16:40:12+02:00",41.463978],["2017-04-20T16:41:13+02:00",41.705],["2017-04-20T16:42:13+02:00",56.791176],["2017-04-20T16:43:13+02:00",50.905403],["2017-04-20T16:44:14+02:00",43.78023],["2017-04-20T16:45:15+02:00",44.8889],["2017-04-20T16:46:16+02:00",55.961487],["2017-04-20T16:47:18+02:00",47.1194],["2017-04-20T16:48:18+02:00",50.75987],["2017-04-20T16:49:18+02:00",54.588047],["2017-04-20T16:50:19+02:00",41.76504],["2017-04-20T16:51:19+02:00",42.203316],["2017-04-20T16:52:19+02:00",47.71752],["2017-04-20T16:53:19+02:00",42.00233],["2017-04-20T16:54:19+02:00",42.788067],["2017-04-20T16:55:19+02:00",48.41838],["2017-04-20T16:56:20+02:00",57.863647],["2017-04-20T16:57:20+02:00",48.42648],["2017-04-20T16:58:20+02:00",51.776695],["2017-04-20T16:59:20+02:00",58.655876],["2017-04-20T17:00:20+02:00",48.769646],["2017-04-20T17:01:20+02:00",58.32432],["2017-04-20T17:02:20+02:00",42.196297]]);
    var options = {
      title: 'Portata Misuratore',
      hAxis: {title: 'Data/Ora',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

As you can see I commented the command that should add data, but it results in an empty page. The following line is the same data put explicitly in the command and this way it works. What's wrong with my code?

The web page is here: http://precursori.altervista.org/php_test/google_graph.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonData` needs to be parsed, try...

```
data.addRows(JSON.parse(jsonData));
```